# Not able to transfer mysql table data to cassandra using Nifi

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi, kylo

I'm trying to migrate mysql table data into cassandra using nifi. Attaching screenshot of what I have tried in nifi as I stuck at putCassandraQl command as it is throwing the error which is mentioned in attached screenshot. Please help me on this as i need to add more steps.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PutCassandraQL requires the flow file to contain a CQL statement, where you are passing in the Avro records you're getting from QueryDatabaseTable, or after trying to modify the contents with ReplaceText.

Try the following:

QDT -> SplitAvro -> ConvertAvroToJSON -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> ReplaceText (to change SQL to CQL) -> PutCassandraQL

**EDIT**: PutCassandraQL is expecting parameters in attributes of the form `cql.args.N.type` and `cql.args.N.value` where N is a positive integer corresponding to the position of the value to be inserted. However ConvertJSONToSQL outputs attributes of the form `sql.args.N.type` and `sql.args.N.value`. This means you'll need to change them using UpdateAttribute or ExecuteScript. As of NiFi 1.5.0 (not yet released at the time of this writing) via [NIFI-4684](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4684), you'll be able to specify the prefix of the attributes coming out of ConvertJSONToSQL, so you can set that property to `cql`.

You may not need a ReplaceText if what is generated by ConvertJSONToSQL is valid CQL. If it is not, you will need to use ReplaceText to change the SQL statement into valid CQL.

Comment: @ mattyb At putCassandraQl an exception is throwing 'Invalid unset value for column name' , as we are getting values like VALUES(?,?,?,?).

Comment: Could you please let me know the configuration properties for ReplaceText.

Comment: Thank you @ mattyb, I'm able to migrate data to cassandra now.

Comment: could you share the nifi template file ? I am new and finding it time consuming to setup attributes for similar task